# Pandas: consolidating columns in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Using the DataFrame below as an example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, 3, 2, 1] , 'col2':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B','C']})

   col1 col2
0     1    A
1     2    A
2     3    B
3     2    B
4     1    C
```

how can I get

```
   col1  col2  
0   1     A,C  
1   2     A,B
2   3     B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby) on 'col1' and then [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply) a lambda that joins the values:

```
In [88]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1, 2, 3, 2, 1] , 'col2':['A', 'A', 'B', 'B','C']})
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(x)).reset_index()

Out[88]:
   col1 col2
0     1  A,C
1     2  A,B
2     3    B
```